# What is a faster way to get an object from array using find index, or getting value at a key of a map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Method 1 is using an array which contains objects and i want to get an object with a certain ID.
The second method is suing map, in which an object is created at "id" key.

To get object from array

```
array.findIndex((x) => x.id == id)
```

and to get object from map is simple

```
Map.get(id)
```

I want to know which method is faster and better

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: `.findIndex` is `O(n)` while `map.get` is `O(1)`.

Comment: That is a different question, i saw that before posting this question. I am talking about Map which has key value pairs, not about method of array

Comment: @mplungjan Neither of the two questions you linked as duplicates are related to `Map` lookups?

Comment: Apologies. I am sure there is a better dupe out there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Big O notation is how long an algorithm takes to execute depending on how
>   long is the input and usually talking about the unfavorable case scenario.

When you use `array.findIndex((x) => x.id == id)`, it means that the whole array should be iterated in the worst case `array.length` times. So the complexity of this method is `O(n)`.

When you use `Map.get(id)`, it means that hash will be calculated and then by this `hash` we can go to the desired item in `Map`. So the complexity of this method is `O(1)`. It is faster.

**UPDATE:**

[Comment by VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz):

> On the flip side, of course, a map takes extra space and processing.
>   So, if you only want to look up one or two items, it's probably not
>   worth it. However, if you have lots of lookups, it will have a massive
>   benefit speed-wise. Just throwing it out there. I'd personally opt for
>   a Map.

Comment: On the flip side, of course, a map takes extra space and processing. So, if you only want to look up one or two items, it's probably not worth it. However, if you have lots of lookups, it will have a massive benefit speed-wise. Just throwing it out there. I'd personally opt for a Map.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for the great comment. In my view, the comment should be included in the answer as it is very useful. I believe that you will approve it:).

Answer (score 2):

## It Depends

In theory you should use Big O notation to decide. As noted, `.findIndex` is O(n) while `map.get` is O(1), which simply means `map.get` is more efficient. However, in practice, there are many other considerations. For example:

What is the the size of the data? Does it comes already as an array and you need to Map it? How many lookups you need to perform?

On a very small array, simple lookup (`for` loop, not `.findIndex`, because of the additional function call) might be more efficient. On very large array, mapping takes time, few lookups will be more efficient than mapping.

Consider the following code, for large size array, two lookups, mapping  will be highly inefficient. Only above ~15-20 lookups (depend on your CPU, memory speed, ETC), mapping will be more efficient.

```js
'use strict';

const gen_arr = size => {
  const arr = [];
  while (size) {
    arr.push({ id:size, data:size.toString() });
    --size;
  }
  return arr;
};

const map_it = arr => {
  const map = new Map();
  for (let obj of arr) {
    map.set(obj.id, obj);
  }
  return map;
}

// Assume nodejs if no performance
const perf = typeof performance != 'undefined' ? performance : { now: ()=> Number(process.hrtime.bigint() / 1000000n) };
let t = perf.now();
const timeit = msg => { const t1 = perf.now(); console.log(msg, 'took', t1 - t, 'ms'); t = t1; };
const start_timer = () => t = perf.now();

const arr_size = 1000000;
const arr = gen_arr(arr_size);

start_timer();
let r = arr.find(obj => obj.id === 1); // end
timeit(`finding ${JSON.stringify(r)} in array`);
r = arr.find(obj => obj.id === arr_size);
timeit(`finding ${JSON.stringify(r)} in array`);
let map = map_it(arr);
timeit('mapping');
r = map.get(1);
timeit(`finding ${JSON.stringify(r)} in map`);
r = map.get(arr_size);
timeit(`finding ${JSON.stringify(r)} in map`);
```